# migrating my wordpress site

Tags: migration

So I recently changed the name of my base directory of my WordPress installation and then changed the `home` and `siteurl` and did a better search replace in my database then I changed the permalink structure from 'custom' to the second to last setting but now I cannot edit or create new pages... How do I fix the site so it will work again?

---

I worked around the problem by doing a fresh install of WordPress with a new database and then rebuilding my site so now I do not have the problem anymore but I still would like to know why changing the permalinks on two different servers (one unix and one windows) caused new page creation to stop working. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you seeing exactly when you try to edit or create?

Also! Have you updated the Permalinks? (simply visit the Permalinks page to regenerate them) `WP-Admin > Settings > Permalinks`

Usually fixes 99.99% of issues when you have issues navigating away from the home page.

Comment: When I press 'Publish' on a new page I got the alert `Failed to Publish`.  And yes I tried changing the permalinks and then saving, but that is what causes the problem.  I updated my question with where I am now.